# JavaScript div clone not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I clone a div, I right click on the div and it marks the border with black line around the div. If I press clone, it clones. All good till here.

However, if I select a div, and now select some other div, black lines are seen on both of them (I only need it to be seen on the last one selected) and both of them gets cloned.

Below is my JS code clone function:

```
  clone(){ 
    var thisDiv = $("#addDiv .clickedDiv");
    $(thisDiv).clone().insertAfter(thisDiv);
    $(thisDiv).removeClass('clickedDiv');
    $(thisDiv).siblings('.clickedDiv').removeClass('clickedDiv');
    $("#ctxMenu").hide();
  }
```

I think thisDiv keeps adding all the div's on which I right click, but I need only the last one.

Attached image below:

[image]

As you can see I right clicked on one div, then on second and then on third; all three are seen selected, whereas `thisDiv` should have the value of last Div which is selected.

### Edit

Below is the code which is used to highlight black border. I only want the last selected div to be in black.

```
if($(event.target).hasClass('context_menu')){
$(event.target).addClass('clickedDiv');
}
else{
$(event.target).parent().addClass('clickedDiv');
}
```

Comment: Please try setting different `id` on each `div` that you are creating. The mentioned issue appears when multiple `div` elements have same `id` attribute.

Comment: I am sure there is a way without giving different id's  and how can the black border be removed from the previously selected div ?  I only want it to appear on the latest selected

Comment: I suggest you look into the right click event that sets the `clickedDiv` class on the selected `div`. You'll see that it sets the mentioned class on all `div` elements with `addDiv` id.

Comment: Alright, I'll find that code and update my question in next 60 mins and then you can give me a better suggestion

Comment: You should not have multiple elements on a page with the same ID, it will cause unexpected behaviour and is also invalid.